# Exercise on higher order Bernstein type estimates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, ricci-flow

I was reading *Ricci flow: Techniques and Applications (Part - II: Analytic Aspects)* by *B. Chow et al.* In Chapter $14$ section $6$ there is an exercise stating:

> Exercise $14.24$: Prove higher derivative Bernstein-type estimates for the local heat equation.

I was unable to find any reference online to deal the problem. I could not understand the term "higher derivative estimates".

Can somebody provide me an example or article related to this type of estimation (involving higher derivatives)? In addition if some applications (like how to derive Harnack inequality for this estimation) can be provided then it would be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you @ViktorStein for this information. Could you provide some more info in this context. Any books you recommend? How this Bernstein polynomial is connected to heat equation etc.? Thanks again!

Comment: I take back, what I just said, something that fits your description can be found [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Bernstein_method) (might contain spoilers).